# How to get one byte char from byte in postgresql query?

Tags: postgresql

I interested in how to write char in query by the unicode index or byte format(0x27)

So want to get something like that

`COPY test_table FROM '/tmp/tests/test.csv' WITH DELIMITER '0x27' CSV`

The real need is to insert CSV into postgres with unprintable delimiter

But if it is not possible to use unprintable symbols in `COPY...` query, i would like to know anyway is it possible to write char by byte difinition, like in example or near that?

Yea, i read documentation, but didint find any examples, and i was searching for answer in many places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify any character using extended string literals and UNICODE escapes:

```
... DELIMITER E'\u001B'
```

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) for details.